# How to parse dates for incomplete dates in Python

Tags: python

I am using dateutil.parser to parse dates and I want to throw an exception if the date is incomplete i.e January 1 (missing year) or January 2016 (missing day). So far I have the following

```
try: 
    parse(date)
    return parse(date).isoformat()
except ValueError:
    return 'invalid'
```

Comment: What is your question? Given code is correct. (From the [doc](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) it is clear `parse` raises `ValueError` for invalid or unknown string format.)

Comment: "I want to throw an exception if the date is incomplete i.e January 1 (missing year) or January 2016 (missing day)" Right now datteutil inserts a default date if the year or month etc is missing. I want to invalidate the date altogether in those cases.

Comment: @TatianaFrank : if  "January 1" is the given date, do you want to throw exception like "missing year" or  if  "January 1" is the given date and you want to throw exception like "invalid date"

Comment: yes, it doesnt matter really what the exception is, as long as I have some indicator that I can use in a condition

Comment: @TatianaFrank got your question. It is difficult to do since `parse` has `default` parameter from which it fills the missing date components. If you try to pass `None` to `default`(which is also its default value) internally it replaces it with current date, this can be seen from the [source code](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/master/dateutil/parser.py#L549-L552). I found a simple way of solving your problem which uses internal function `_parse` of class `dateutil.parser.parser`. I'll add that below in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse takes a default argument from which it takes the unspecified parts. So the easiest solution (apart from using a different library) would be to call the function with two *different* default parameters.

If both calls return the same value the datetime is valid, otherwise some default value was used - you can even find out what was unspecified this way.

Comment: Yes - nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use private method `_parse` of class `dateutil.parser.parser` to determine if day, month and year have been supplied. Since the method is private its behaviour may change and it is generally not advisable to use private methods of other classes in production code, but in this particular case using it is the most easy and robust method, so its probably OK.

Modified code looks like:

```
from dateutil.parser import parser, parse

# Check if passed date is complete and valid
def is_date_complete (date, must_have_attr=("year","month","day")):
    parse_res, _ = parser()._parse(date)
    # If date is invalid `_parse` returns (None,None)
    if parse_res is None:
        return False
    # For a valid date `_result` object is returned. E.g. _parse("Sep 23") returns (_result(month=9, day=23), None)
    for attr in must_have_attr:
        if getattr(parse_res,attr) is None:
            return False
    return True

## your code section
if not is_date_complete(date):
    return 'invalid'
else:
    return parse(date).isoformat()
```

Here we utilized result of `_parse` to determine if the date has missing year, month or day.

Answer (score 2):

The parser uses datetime.today() to fill in missing values. If you pass in a date to the `default` parameter of parse, parse will use that date for missing values. By passing in two default dates with different values for year, month, and day, we can compare the parse results and see if they differ.

```
jan_01_2001 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/01', '%m/%d/%y')
feb_02_2002 = datetime.datetime.strptime('02/02/02', '%m/%d/%y')

complete_date = 'May 4, 2017'
incomplete_date = 'May 4'

print parse(complete_date, default=jan_01_2001) == parse(complete_date, default=feb_02_2002)
# True

print parse(incomplete_date, default=jan_01_2001) == parse(incomplete_date, default=feb_02_2002)
# False
```

Comment: Smart solution :)